# How do I check if audio is buffering?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I'm creating my audio element with `new Audio()`, however when adding the event listener `'waiting'`, it triggers right away when I press play and does not actually trigger when it starts buffering.

Code:

```
var source = new Audio('some-url');

source.addEventListener('waiting', function () {
    alert('Buffering');
};

source.play()
```

So `'waiting'` triggers right away, but it doesn't trigger again when audio starts buffering after playing, however it also triggers ONCE if I seek the track (even on localhost). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for me this worked:

```
var source, sourceTime, dateTime;
source = new Audio('some-url');

function compare() {
    var difference = Math.abs(sourceTime - dateTime);
    if (difference > 1000) {
        alert('buffering!');
    }
};

source.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
    var date, time;
    date = new Date();
    time = date.getTime();
    sourceTime = date;
});

function updateTime() {
    var date, time;
    date = new Date();
    time = date.getTime();
    dateTime = time;
    compare();
    setTimeout(updateTime(), 50);
};

source.play()
updateTime();
```

The reason you need to check if difference is greater than 1000 is because `timeupdate` event is inconsistent and might sometimes be exactly one second differ.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior you're seeing from the `waiting` event is as expected per Mozilla documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events):

> **waiting**
>
> Sent when the requested operation (such as playback) is delayed pending the completion of another operation (such as a seek).

To get progress of media download, you'll want to listen to either `loadstart` for a one-time event or `progress` for a recurring event:

> **loadstart**
>
> Sent when loading of the media begins.
>
> **progress**
>
> Sent periodically to inform interested parties of progress downloading the media. Information about the current amount of the media that has been downloaded is available in the media element's buffered attribute.

```
var source = new Audio();

source.addEventListener('waiting', function () {
    window.alert('Waiting');
};

source.addEventListener('loadstart', function () {
    window.alert("Loading");
};

source.addEventListener('progress', function () {
    // do something, eg:
    var timeRanges = source.buffered;
    if (timeRanges && timeRanges.length > 0) {
        console.log(timeRanges);
        // do something with the TimeRanges object
    }
};

source.play()
```

Comment: I ended up using getTime() from a Date object and then comparing those with the timeupdate event (which stops when it starts buffering) with the current Date.getTime(). Works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late but this should do

```
let slowInternetTimeout = null;

source.addEventListener('loadstart', function () {
    //show buffering
    alert('Buffering');
});
source.addEventListener('waiting', () => {
slowInternetTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    //show buffering
    alert('Buffering');
    });
});
source.addEventListener('playing', () => {
if(slowInternetTimeout != null){
    clearTimeout(slowInternetTimeout);
    slowInternetTimeout = null;
    //continue playing
    alert('Play continues');
    }
});
```